# Kotlin Coroutine - async using call all functions at same time (parallel - without milliseconds delay)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

// Code

```
suspend fun main() {
        sendDataAndAwaitAcknowledge()
    }

suspend fun sendDataAndAwaitAcknowledge() = coroutineScope {

    awaitAll(async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("1"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("2"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("3"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("4"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("5"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("6"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("7"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("8"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("9"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("10"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("11"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("12"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("13"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("14"))
    }, async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println(currTime("15"))
    }
    )
}

fun currTime(str: String): String {
    val dtf: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    val now: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
    return "count: $str  + time: ${dtf.format(now)}"
}
```

// Output

```
count: 7  + time: 12:29:17.089
count: 1  + time: 12:29:17.089
count: 5  + time: 12:29:17.089
count: 8  + time: 12:29:17.089
count: 2  + time: 12:29:17.089
count: 11  + time: 12:29:17.089
count: 14  + time: 12:29:17.089
count: 10  + time: 12:29:17.090
count: 6  + time: 12:29:17.089
count: 12  + time: 12:29:17.090
count: 13  + time: 12:29:17.090
count: 15  + time: 12:29:17.089
count: 4  + time: 12:29:17.090
count: 3  + time: 12:29:17.090
count: 9  + time: 12:29:17.089
```

In the above output **089**, **090** this variation happens some times same time executes, some times more difference.

**Expected Result:**

**Need all function trigger without milliseconds delay**. If it is possible please share your points else how to achieve this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your machine doesn't have an infinite amount of cores to execute all the code in parallel. You cannot guarantee that everything runs at exactly the same time.

Comment: I don't think you can get such precision with standard solutions like launching coroutines, submitting to executors, starting threads, etc. Application can't control when the operating system will have required resources and even if CPU cores are free, we don't know when exactly a thread will be resumed. You would need a more specialized solution like your workers running all the time with some busy waiting. But generally, it sounds like a very unusual need and hard to get right. Can I ask why do you need this? Maybe there is a better solution to your problem.

Comment: @broot My aim was call the function to execute same time as parallel.